# Problem with Enterprise Distribution Over 3G

Tags: iphone, distribution, enterprise

I am trying to distribute an enterprise application, but I am having trouble when users try to download the app over a 3G connection. I've created the proper manifest file and it points correctly to the .ipa location. I am able to download and install the application fine over a Wi-Fi network, but when I switch off Wi-Fi, I am no longer able to download the app. Rather than a successful installation, I get the "Unable to download" pop up.

My application size is only 440K, so it is not subject to file size limits.

Does anyone know what would be causing this? Help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need more details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, our web server was experiencing network latency. I believe we were losing the connection to Apple's server, which was verifying our application's enterprise status. Eventually the latency cleared up and we were able to download the file with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Is the your ipa file and manifest on a public server, or is it on an internal server?  When you're using the 3G connection you're only able to see machines that are public.  When you're using wi-fi you can see machines that are on a local network or intranet.

Comment: The ipa file is on a public server, so they shouldn't experience any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think our webserver was experiencing network latency and was losing the connection to Apple's server. I need to learn more about the process the iPhone goes through when downloading an enterprise app, but in the meantime this has been solved. Thanks again for your suggestion.